$O(|V||E|)$ algorithm for finding all the cut vertices in a connected graph
Given a connected graph $G = (V, E)$, how to find all the cut vertices in $G$ in $O(|V||E|)$ time?
I have considered some algorithms for finding all cut vertices in a connected graph as follows. However, none of them are in $O(|V||E|)$ time complexity.
Method 1
I have heard we can construct an algorithm based on the proof of Menger's theorem (Vertex connectivity). However, I have also heard that the time complexity is $O(\sqrt(|V|)|E|)$.
Method 2
Tarjan algorithm is the algorithm for finding cut vertices, but it's time complexity is $O(|V|+|E|)$.
I would appreciate it if you could give me some hints.

Both of the algorithms you mentioned are in $\mathcal{O} (VE)$ time. Perhaps you mean $\Theta(VE)$ ?

＠Enhm Thank you very much for your comment and answer. I have looked up the question again and find it was not $O(|V||E|)$, but $o(|V||E|)$. I am wondering if the Tarjan's algorithm is $o(|V||E|)$?

Yes it is. I advise you to relook the definitions of these notations

Assuming you meant $\Theta(VE)$ time. One naive algorithm is

Go over all vertices $v$

construct a new graph after removing that vertex
run a  dfs to check number of components in new graph
if number of components $> 1$, $v$ is a cut vertex.



Time complexity here is $V \cdot \mathcal{\Theta}(V +E) = \mathcal{\Theta}(VE)$
Another weird algorithm is

Run tarjan to get cut vertices in $\Theta(V+E)$
Initialize $ x \leftarrow 0$
For all vertices $v$

For all edges $e$

Update $x \leftarrow x+1$





This algorithm also runs in $\Theta(VE)$

Please use cardinality notations to represent the size of a set.

@codeR It's pretty unambiguous in this context on what is meant.

Thank you for your answer. I have understand that the first algorithm you mentioned is $O(|V||E|)$ (and also $o(|V||E|)$. However, I am not sure about the 2nd alrogithm itself. What is the purpose of the 3rd step, which is a for loop on $v$ and $e$, after running the Tarjan's algorithm. I think only the first step (Tarjan) is enough to get cut vertices, but does the 2nd and 3rd is used to make the algorithm $\Theta(|V||E|)$?

@XYJ The first algorithm is not $\mathcal{o}(|V||E|)$. Yes to your 2nd question, its just used to add more steps in algorithm to increase the time complexity

@EnEm Thank you very much for answering my questions. I have relooked the definition and understand that the first algorithm is $\Theta(|V||E|)$, but not $o(|V||E|)$ since the time complexity is not less than (but not include equal to) $o(|V||E|)$.

@EnEm What is ambiguous? It is a sin to write the set in asymptotic notations like $O(V+E)$. One argument is that the running time is expressed in terms of the input size, not the input itself. One must use the cardinality of the sets and write $O(|V|+|E|)$.
